# Html upload profile picture without distorting the image

Tags: html, css

I would like to upload a profile picture of a user on the page, but my problem is that the users upload different kinds of images. Some of them, the height is too big, some the width is too big.
Currently, Im stretching the image, and it is affecting image quality.

I want to be able to do it like dating sites such as baadoo etc.

How can i achieve this?

Or which third party upload control can i use to achieve this.

```
 background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

Comment: `object-fit: contain;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this (basically what Nikita and Najam suggested, but with an example)

```css
/* IGNORE THIS SECTION */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
/* IGNORE THIS SECTION */




.image-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.image {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/1300/900" alt="">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this css . If not, let me know.

```
.someClassName {
   width:100%;
   height:550px;
   object-fit:cover;
   object-position:50% 50%;
  }
```